# Create an array, which contains 4 pointers that point to 4 2d arrays of type char

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
char songsArtist1[3][80];
  //Songs for Artist 2
  char songsArtist2[3][80];
  //Songs for Artist 3
  char songsArtist3[3][80];
  //Songs for Artist 4
  char songsArtist4[3][80];
```

I have these 4 arrays of type char, which contain a null terminated string in each row.

```
char (*pt1)[MAX_LENGTH] = songsArtist1;
char (*pt2)[MAX_LENGTH] = songsArtist2;
char (*pt3)[MAX_LENGTH] = songsArtist3;
char (*pt4)[MAX_LENGTH] = songsArtist4;

printf("\n%s\n", pt1[0]);
```

I then defined these pointers which I can successfully use to access the first string in the first array.
My question is how can I now put these 4 pointers into their own array, which I want to use later on to swap some of the pointers with each other(I will pass them through 1 or 2 functions to do so). Any explanation or help is much appreciated.

I tried this but I honestly knew I was throwing punches in the dark here

```
char *ptrarray[4] = {pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4};

printf("\n%s\n", ptrarray[0][0]);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is `MAX_LENGTH`? Why don't you use it do define your arrays as well?

Comment: This code only works if `MAX_LENGTH` is `80`.  Either use `MAX_LENGTH` consistently, or don't use it at all.  Mixing the two is the worst of both worlds.

Comment: "these 4 arrays of type char" Actually, you have 4 arrays of type "array of char". And you have pointers of type "pointer to array of char". But you try to store them in an array that just holds "pointer to char". Your compiler should say something about that. And whenever you get warnings and errors, you should include the complete and exact messages in your question

Comment: Assuming you fix the hard-wired `80` bug, then you want the elements of `ptarray` to have type `char (*)[MAX_LENGTH]`.  So, just declare it:  `char (*ptarray[4])[MAX_LENGTH] = {pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4};`  Note you can omit the length, in which case it is taken from the initializer length, i.e.  `char (*ptarray[])[MAX_LENGTH] = {pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4};`